# MongoDB group by part of Integer value

Tags: integer, substring, long-integer

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("528dd86bd6188ad3e9c0c8ea"),
"id" : "CA002303986",
"data" : NumberLong(20000101),
"element" : "TMAX",
"value1" : -300,
"mflag1" : "",
"qflag1" : "",
"sfalg1" : "G",
"lcol" : ""
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("528dd86bd6188ad3e9c0c8eb"),
"id" : "CA002303986",
"data" : NumberLong(20000101),
"element" : "TMIN",
"value1" : -345,
"mflag1" : "",
"qflag1" : "",
"sfalg1" : "G",
"lcol" : ""
}
```

The field data which is a NumberLong is actually date. I would like to use group by function on it on first 4 digits which is the year. Is there a way to do that in MongoDB?
I was able to do that in MySQL by turning it first into string then taking a substring and running group by on that substring. But there is a lot of data for MySQL to handle.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate({$project:{year:{$substr:["$data",0,4]}}},
                           {$group:{_id:{'y':'$year'},count:{$sum:1}}})
```